# What are the yellow and green glowing objects in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made an end portal and defeated the ender dragon. What is the yellow and green stuff I collect? (I am on creative mode.)

Comment: Sounds like XP (experience) orbs to me. Have you not killed any mobs before?

Comment: no i build and dont kill becuase it doesnt attack me :3 but i got bored and wanted to leave the end so yeah :3

Comment: Cool. If you switch to survival (/gamemode 0) you should see that you have an xp bar and you probably have around 100 levels now.

Comment: But how could you have gotten to the end without killing anything? Unless you were in creative mode or you had someone do all the dirty work for you, I don't really understand how you couldn't have seen it.

Comment: @lumbricuslubricant in creative mode one can create any items so there's infinite Eyes of Ender which can lead one to the stronghold and to open the portal. getting to the end is easy without killing once but it's still cheating and obviously even if you kill only the Enderdragon you don't get the achievement (having need to kill a monster at least one to get a pre-requisite achievement)

Answer (score 11):

Those are [experience orbs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience_Orb)!:

[image]

> An Experience Orb is an entity similar to an item entity, an orb that fades between a green and yellow color.

Experience orbs drop in the following situations:

- When a killed mob's corpse vanishes
- When a player is killed
- When animals breed
- When mining any ore that drops its mineral (that is, not iron, gold, or any use of Silk Touch).
- When you break a Bottle o' Enchanting.
- Mining (destroying) a spawner block
- Breeding animals.

You also gain experience (but no experience orbs will drop) from:

- Smelting any of various items.
- Fishing.
- Trading with villagers.

When you collect experience orbs your are rewarded with experience points.

According to the "[Experience Orb](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience_Orb)" page on the wiki, you collected 12,000 experience points from killing the Ender Dragon:

> The Ender Dragon drops 11 huge orbs totalling 12,000 experience points.

When you collect enough experience points you will level up. You can use your levels for [Enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting), or to use an [Anvil](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvils).

Comment: You also get XP from removing smelted items from a furnace, trading with villagers (1.8), fishing, mining mob spawners, and from Bottles O' Enchanting, which can be obtained in Creative mode or by trading with a Priest villager.

Comment: @Johonn thanks for the comment, I edited my post a bit.

Comment: Good distinction that the orbs don't always drop.